# Tic Tac Toe personal project

Tags: java, game, tic-tac-toe

This is a Tic Tac Toe game in Java in preparation for my seconds personal project (chess game). I'm having a little problem though and am thinking that my `for` loop to create those buttons is a mistake. I believe I should instantiate all 9 `JButton`s implicitly instead of using a `for` loop because then I know for sure I will be able to compare each and every button. What are your thoughts?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by Usman on 5/17/2016.
 */
public class TicTacToeGUI extends JPanel {

    boolean turn = true;

    public TicTacToeGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        for(int i=0 ; i<9 ; i++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton("");
            btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,60));
            btn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(btn.isEnabled()){
                        if(turn){
                            btn.setText("X");
                            turn = !turn;
                        }
                        else{
                            btn.setText("O");
                            turn = true;
                        }
                        btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        TicTacToeGUI game = new TicTacToeGUI();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first quesiton.

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop isn't inherently wrong, the problem you're anticipating though is right -- you won't have a way of comparing and referencing the buttons since they all become anonymous with your current approach.

Instead, use an array of `JButton` and simply use the iterator of the loop to instantiate at that location which you can later utilize as an index to reference a specific JButton.

```
JButton[0] board = new JButton[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        board[i] = new JButton("");
    }
```

On the topic of anonymity, as of Java 8 rather than using anonymous inner classes for Action Events you can use Lambda Expressions.

So, you can replace this chunk of code:

> ```
>  btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
> ```

With:

```
btn.addActionListener(e -> {
```

Of course, you close the bracket. This also has the benefit of no longer requiring you to import `ActionEvent` and `ActionListener` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Think about making your variable names indicate what it is they represent.  Instead of having `turn`, how about calling it something like `playXNext`.

Try to be consistent with the way you set the variable.  Either do this:

```
if(playXNext){
    btn.setText("X");
} else {                        
    btn.setText("O");
}                
playXNext = !playXNext;
```

Or do this:

```
if(playXNext){
    btn.setText("X");
    playXNext = false;
} else {                        
    btn.setText("O");
    playXNext = true;
}
```

Whilst both approaches work, if you mix them, for the same variable close together, it just makes the code a little bit harder to read.